# Loading custom fonts in React Native is giving error

Tags: react-native, fonts, expo

fontFamily "pro" is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync.

- If you intended to use a system font, make sure you typed the name correctly and that it is supported by your device operating system.

## - If this is a custom font, be sure to load it with Font.loadAsync.

But if I dismiss the error I see that the font has loaded.

Here is my code:

```
    export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {loading: true};
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    await Font.loadAsync({
      pro: require('./assets/fonts/MavenPro-Regular.ttf'),
      medium: require('./assets/fonts/MavenPro-Medium.ttf'),
    }).then(() => {
      this.setState({loading: false});
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <NavigationContainer>
          {
            <Drawer.Navigator
              drawerType={'slide'}
              drawerContent={(props) => <DrawerContent {...props} />}>
              <Drawer.Screen
                name="Home"
                component={HomeStackScreen}
                options={{
                  swipeEnabled: false,
                }}
              />
            </Drawer.Navigator>
          }
        </NavigationContainer>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're not delaying presenting the app based on the loading state, so you are rendering the app before the font has loaded, thus the error.

notice in [this example](https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-custom-fonts/#a-minimal-but-complete-working-example) that the `AppLoading` component is rendered while loading fonts, you can use this if you want, or whatever else you would like to display.

---

also, not related to your question but fyi you don't need to use `then()` if you're using `await`

```
await doSomething();
this.setState({ done: true });
```