# React native Expo Custom font android issue

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, fonts, expo

I tried using a custom font Avenir-book.tff and AvernirNext.otf for my expo project. For some reason my custom font works in my iOS device but doesn't work for my android device. Here my code:
app.js:

```
UNSAFE_componentWillMount() {
Font.loadAsync({
  "Avenir-Book": require("./assets/fonts/Avenir-Book.ttf"),
  "Avenir-Next": require("./assets/fonts/AvenirNextLTPro-Bold.otf"),
}).then(() => this.setState({ fontsLoaded: true }));
}
```

my text:

```
<Text style={styles.text}>ORA</Text>
```

Style sheet:

```
text: {
color: colors.white,
fontSize: 30,
fontFamily: "Avenir-Book",
fontWeight: "bold",
marginTop: 8,
},
```

I tried using both the fonts. Both works perfectly fine on iOS but doesn't work at all on android. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Try this way : `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eyoISNRKVlM&t=229s`

Comment: Didn't work @SagarKulkarni

Answer (score 0):

I think this answer is relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62460424/659988

Be sure to refer to this minimal and complete working example in the documentation too: https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-custom-fonts/#a-minimal-but-complete-working-example

Comment: Issue seems to persist